# Karma test failing due to Zone.js TypeError: Cannot read property 'takeUntil' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, zone.js

Experiencing (**TypeError: Cannot read property 'takeUntil' of undefined**) running this test.  This is related to Zone.js.

The component is behaving fine in the app, just the test is failing?

Some more details to keep you happy

This is the component I am trying to test

```
// Import: Angular
import {Component, EventEmitter, Injectable, Input, Output} from 
'@angular/core';

// Component
@Component({
  selector: 'currency-input',
  templateUrl: './currency-input.html'
})
@Injectable()
export class CurrencyInput {

  @Input() public currencyValue: string;
  @Input() public valid: boolean;
  @Input() public errorMessage: string;
  @Output() public onChange: any = new EventEmitter();

  public currencyInputChange(e: any): void {
    this.onChange.emit(e);
  }
}
```

This is the test:

```
describe('CurrencyInput', () => {
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CurrencyInput> = null;
let instance: any = null;

beforeEach(async(() => 
   TestUtils.beforeEachCompiler([CurrencyInput]).then(compiled => {
   fixture = compiled.fixture;
   instance = compiled.instance;
   instance.currencyValue = 'some_value';
   fixture.detectChanges();
})));

  it('defined', () => {
    expect(fixture).not.toBeNull();
    expect(instance).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Stack Trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'takeUntil' of undefined
    at TextInput.webpackJsonp.../../../../ionic-angular/components/input/input.js.TextInput._enableHideCaretOnScroll Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.js:440:1)
    at new TextInput Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.js:155:1)
    at createClass Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12173:1)
    at createDirectiveInstance Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:12010:22)
    at createViewNodes Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13448:38)
    at callViewAction Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13880:1)
    at execComponentViewsAction Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13789:1)
    at createViewNodes Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13476:1)
    at createRootView Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13338:1)
    at callWithDebugContext Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14739:26)
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'takeUntil' of undefined
    at resolvePromise Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:824:1)
    at resolvePromise Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:795:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:873:1
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:103:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:1)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:1)
    at <anonymous>
Expected null not to be null.
    at UserContext.<anonymous> Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/src/components/currency-input/currency-input.spec.ts:23:25)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
Expected null not to be null.
    at UserContext.<anonymous> Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/src/components/currency-input/currency-input.spec.ts:24:26)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke Users/larry/Projects/turbo-ionic/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:1)
```

Comment: please provide a repo to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing fixture.detectChanges() from beforeEach -- that seems like a common issue that returns this error.

Comment: I have tried removing fixture.detectChanges(), doesn't seem to make a difference.